# C++: void value not ignored as it ought to be

Tags: c++, function, reference, arguments

The error is with:

```
estimate1 = leibnizPi (nTerms, estimatedV1);
```

&

```
estimate2 = wallisPi (nTerms, estimatedValue2);
```

I'm thinking it has to do with the way it is set up to reference the estimatedValue in the function, or the way it is being called is incorrect.

Any help is much appreciated!

NOTE: HAS TO REMAIN VOID. Sorry about that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

//
// This program will be used in the second assignment (functions)
//

using namespace std;

const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;


void leibnizPi (int numberofterms, double &estimatedValue1 )
{

    double sign = 1.0;
    double sum = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberofterms; ++i) {
        double denominator = 2.0 * i + 1.0;
        double term = 4.0 / denominator;
        sum = sum + sign * term;
        sign = -sign;
    }
    estimatedValue1 = sum;
}

void wallisPi (int numberofterms, double &estimatedValue2)
{
    double product = 1.0;

    for (int i = 1; i < numberofterms; ++i) {
        double r = 2.0*i;
        r = r*r;
        double term = r/(r-1.0);
        product = product * term;
    }
    estimatedValue2 = 2.0 * product;

}


double abstractError (double computedValue);

double relativeError (double computedValue);

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
     double estimate1 = 0;
     double absErr1 = 0;
     double relErr1 = 0;
     double estimate2 = 0;
     double absErr2 = 0;
     double relErr2 = 0;
     double estimatedV1 = 0;
     double estimatedValue2 = 0;

    for (int nTerms = 1; nTerms < 100001; nTerms = nTerms * 4) {
        // Estimate Pi by two different methods

        // Leibniz' sum
        estimate1 =  leibnizPi (nTerms, estimatedV1);
        absErr1 =   abstractError (estimate1);
        relErr1 =   relativeError (estimate1);

        // Wallis' product
        estimate2 =  wallisPi (nTerms, estimatedValue2);
        absErr2 =  abstractError (estimate2);
        relErr2 =  relativeError (estimate2);

        cout << "After " << nTerms << " terms\n";
        cout << "Leibniz' estimate: "<< estimate1 << "\n";
        cout << "Absolute error: " << absErr1
             << "\tRelative error: " << relErr1
             << "\n";

        cout << "Wallis' estimate: "<< estimate2 << "\n";
        cout << "Absolute error: " << absErr2
             << "\tRelative error: " << relErr2
             << "\n";

        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;

}

double abstractFunction (double computedValue)
{
    double abstractError = abs(computedValue - PI);
    return abstractError;
}

double relativeFunction (double computedValue){
    double relativeError1 = abs(computedValue - PI) / PI;
    return relativeError1;
}
```

Comment: Crank up the warning level.

Comment: You say these functions are "for assignment" and must remain `void`. Care to clarificate? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: What do you expect is in the variable estimate1 after it's assign a void value?

Comment: have you tried using pointers?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the return value of a function returning `void`, because there isn't one. Instead, you may want to try something like this:

```
double leibnizPi (int numberofterms, double &estimatedValue1 )
{
    double sign = 1.0;
    double sum = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberofterms; ++i) {
        double denominator = 2.0 * i + 1.0;
        double term = 4.0 / denominator;
        sum = sum + sign * term;
        sign = -sign;
    }
    estimatedValue1 = sum;
    return estimatedValue1;
}

double wallisPi (int numberofterms, double &estimatedValue2)
{
    double product = 1.0;

    for (int i = 1; i < numberofterms; ++i) {
        double r = 2.0*i;
        r = r*r;
        double term = r/(r-1.0);
        product = product * term;
    }
    estimatedValue2 = 2.0 * product;
    return estimatedValue2;
}
```

If you **must** use a `void` function, you should assign the variable passed as a parameter (`estimatedV1`) to the secondary variable (`estimate1`). Like so:

```
leibnizPi (nTerms, estimatedV1);
estimate1 = estimatedV1;
```

Comment: Yes, but it sadly has to remain a void function hence why I attempted to use it as a reference instead.

Answer (score 0):

No, the problem is that you haven't defined your functions to return anything, and than you try to take what they return (which is undefined) and assign it to a variable, which is a mistake.

Define it as such `double leibnizPi (int numberofterms, double &estimatedValue1 )`

And add a return statement.

If you can't change the return type of the function, than don't try to treat it as returning a value. Just write `leibnizPi (nTerms, estimatedV1);` instead of `estimate1 =  leibnizPi (nTerms, estimatedV1);`

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense, but this is for an assignment so it has to remain a void function.

Comment: @JakeAyers, see my edit